# 1 Port on a 10GB network controller is showing UNCLAIMED in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, interface

So my 10GB card is up and one interface ens2f1 is working without issue. However the other interface is appearing as unclaimed. I installed the driver to get the card up origanlly, I can not seem to get it up. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# lshw -C network
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fbd80000-fbdfffff ioport:e020(size=32) memory:fbe04000-fbe07fff memory:90000000-900fffff memory:90100000-901fffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       logical name: ens2f1
       version: 01
       serial: 90:e2:ba:d9:35:b9
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.15.0-76-generic duplex=full firmware=0x000161c1 ip=192.168.1.32 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:66 memory:fbd00000-fbd7ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:fbe00000-fbe03fff memory:90200000-902fffff memory:90300000-903fffff
```

```
:/etc/netplan# nano 00-installer-config.yaml

# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    ens1f0:
      dhcp4: true
    ens1f1:
      dhcp4: true
    ens2f0:
      dhcp4: true
    ens2f1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

```
~# lspci
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
```

```
 ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:4f:fb:84:8c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 0c:c4:7a:da:6c:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfb120000-fb13ffff

eno2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 0c:c4:7a:da:6c:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfb100000-fb11ffff

ens1f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::92e2:baff:fe0d:69fa  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:e2:ba:0d:69:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1967753  bytes 676907032 (676.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8279  bytes 2723306 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfb2a0000-fb2bffff

ens2f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::92e2:baff:fed9:35b9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:e2:ba:d9:35:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 70458136  bytes 9102621381 (9.1 GB)
        RX errors 99  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 99
        TX packets 259370417  bytes 389842021680 (389.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4639125  bytes 1304831929 (1.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4639125  bytes 1304831929 (1.3 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```